# I would be a writer vs I would have been a writer

Tags: difference, conditional-constructions

I want to know what is the difference between these two examples below.

.1 If I had studied English grammar very hard, I would have been a good writer.

.2 If I had studied English grammar very hard, I would  be a good writer.

Comment: Check this out: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if

Answer (score 2):

I agree with JVL's answer up to a point, but he has not quite answered the question. The two sentences under discussion are

> 1) If I had studied English grammar very hard, I would have been a **good** writer.

and

> 2) If I had studied English grammar very hard, I would be a **good** writer.

I have no argument with JVL's analysis of 1) with or without "**good**", but the addition of "**good**" to 2) can change the meaning. It is grammatically correct as it is and means that the speaker **is** a writer now but not a good one, because he didn't study grammar hard enough in the past.

Comment: That means both sentence are correct?

Comment: @ I have forgotten good but  past perfect for the improbable conditional  is not  correct  according to  grammarians

Comment: @AbuOmar. Your second sentence is  grammatically wrong.You can not  find  such  a sentence in any  standard grammar book.Please read  the link  I provided in my answer

Comment: @AbuOmar In my opinion yes, JVL not so much. Not being a grammarian I leave it to them to explain why I am wrong.

Comment: @PeterJennings I see what you are saying. But writing *"I would have been a good writer"* also means *"the speaker is a writer now but not a good one, because he didn't study grammar hard enough in the past."* To me, both versions say that the writer "not a good one".

Comment: @AbuOmar There is nothing wrong with either sentence—they are both grammatical. *Have been* describes a possible past situation; *would be* describes a possible present or future situation.

Comment: @JasonBassford.No standard grammar book  written by native speakers  used the past perfect in the  improbable  conditional(2).How can it be grammatical?

Comment: Mixed conditional we can use them bro.

Comment: I have no wish to start an argument here and I fully respect JVL's answer and point of view (why or who by it's been downvoted is a mystery to me). But just because the construct does not appear in any text book on grammar JVL has read does not ensure that it is invalid. Very few native English speakers have ever heard of the 4 types of conditional sentence listed on Gramarly's site, neither are they conscious of making a distinction when using a conditional. A speaker of idiomatic English would be quite happy with both of the OP's sentences.